# iOS - available disk space is greater than total disk space?

Tags: ios, swift, volume, capacity

I need information about total used space in my app. I am using following methods:

```
func totalDiskSpaceInBytes() -> UInt64 {
    let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory() as String)
    do {
        let values = try fileURL.resourceValues(forKeys: [.volumeTotalCapacityKey])
        let capacity = values.volumeTotalCapacity
        return UInt64(capacity ?? 0)
    } catch {
        return 0
    }
}

func freeDiskSpaceInBytes() -> UInt64 {
    let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory() as String)
    do {
        let values = try fileURL.resourceValues(forKeys: [.volumeAvailableCapacityForImportantUsageKey])
        let capacity = values.volumeAvailableCapacityForImportantUsage
        return UInt64(capacity ?? 0)
    } catch {
        return 0
    }
}
```

For some reason, I am getting higher freeDiskSpaceInBytes than totalDiskSpaceInBytes which is clearly nonsense.

Is there anything wrong with my code please?

Comment: Your code works normal for me in a playground. Are you using Catalyst or any non-standard ways for your iOS app maybe?

Comment: No, I don't use anything non-standard. But it seems to be an iOS 15 bug: [link](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253201053)